# is it possible to put a bigger than 34t chainring on Merida e160?

Tags: shimano, chainring, compatibility

Is it possible to put a bigger than 34t chainring on a Merida e160 MTB? There is only about 2mm of clearance from the chainstay.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean by clearance. *X* or *Y* in the diagram below?

[image]

if you mean *X* then you likely have room for a bigger chainring. If you mean *Y* then you are probably out of luck.

Using a [formula for the radius of an *n* sided polygon](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5264/how-do-i-calculate-the-diameter-of-a-chainring-from-the-number-of-teeth) and assuming tooth profile does not significantly vary for different size chainrings, each additional tooth adds about 2mm of radius to the chainring.